# Como validar um upload pelo nome do arquivo?

Tags: javascript, array, string, file-upload, equals

Estou tentando validar o upload de um arquivo , e o mesmo sempre deve se chamar `new.mpg`, se não, o programa não irá funcionar.

```
function validarNomeArquivo(){
    //variavel que recebe o nome do arquivo
    var  oImg = "bgs/newFile.mpg";
    //variavel para comparar o input 
        var x = document.getElementById('fileBgAtualHD').value;;
                if(x==oImg){
                alert("yes");
                alert(x + " x yes ");
                alert(oImg + "  oImg yes ");
                    return true;
            }
                else{
                    alert("no");
                    alert(x + "  x no");
                    alert(oImg + "  oImg no ");
                    return false;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que ao anexar algum arquivo, o *JavaScript* cria também um **path**, então o `value` do elemento fica mais ou menos assim: `C:\fakepath\nome-do-arquivo.jpg`.

Por esse motivo a condição sempre vai ser falsa no seu código.

Tente deixar sua função assim:

```
function validarNomeArquivo() {
    var oImg = 'new.mpg';
    var x = document.getElementById('fileBgAtualHD').value;

    x = x.split('\\');
    x = x[x.length - 1];

    if (x == oImg) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Deu certo cara ! Obrigada , show de bola :)

Comment: Precisando estamos aí! :D

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a [propriedade name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name) do [objeto File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).

Ficaria

```js
function validaName(el) {
  var name = el.files[0].name
  if (name != 'newFile.mpg') {
    console.log('erro: O nome do arquivo é: ' + name)
  }
}
```

```html
Upload: <input type="file" onchange="validaName(this)" />
```